# Can't build scdf from source, missing dependency : io.pivotal:pivotal-cloudfoundry-client-reactor:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

In maven central repo, there is only 2.2.0-Relase which is available.
https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/io.pivotal/pivotal-cloudfoundry-client-reactor/2.2.0.RELEASE/versions

But scdf has a dependency on io.pivotal:pivotal-cloudfoundry-client-reactor:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE

org.springframework.cloud   spring-cloud-dataflow-platform-cloudfoundry   2.10.0 ->

org.springframework.cloud   spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry            2.8.0  ->

io.pivotal                  pivotal-cloudfoundry-client-reactor           2.1.0

I suppose that maven try to download this dependency from https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot. But now this is impossible : **Not authorized -> [Help 1]**

I can build as i'm lucky to have this dependency in my local repository, probably because i builded scdf a few month ago.

br

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.10.3 release can be built without this problem (the problem was with 2.9.1 release). It seems that Pivotal has changed a lot of things between 2.9.x et 2.10.x and probably fixed some errors and refactor dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions have changed on repo.spring.io
Use https://repo.spring.io/snapshot and https://repo.spring.io/milestone
Unfortunately repo.spring.io/release is not public. We will be publishing an minor version bump to Maven Central soon. You can safely use 2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely upgrade to 2.2.0.RELEASE as it is published to Maven Central.